Is there any way to hide "View all dependencies" option for the user while they're editing a record?
Like the title says, I'd like the users not to see this "View all dependencies" option when they're editing a record.


The "View all dependencies" option is typically part of the user interface for managing field dependencies, and there isn't a direct setting to hide this option for users.
